# Accessing Search Query Text in Google Chrome Browser with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension for myself. I want to access my search bar so that I can feed my queries into my own private ingest server (for realtime processing).

How does one access text entered into the search bar in Chrome? I started here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide but it's unclear where to actually access the query text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do so with a custom keyword preceeding the search.

There is [`chrome.omnibox` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox) that allows you to do it, but you *have* to specify a keyword that needs to be entered first before you start receiving events.

Google specifically does not want you to spy on all searches.

---

Alternatively, you could *try* and tap into the requests sent as part of search suggestions with [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest). I doubt it will be a robust solution though.